Manga about a boy who got kicked out of his family for awakening a lightning blood line ability
I remember reading a full color manga a few years ago maybe 10 I can't remember exactly, it was about a boy who got kicked out of his family for awakening a lightning blood line ability ( I think it was blood line ) they use a machine to awaken them it turns out lightning is the strongest blood line and he has knowledge from the future on how to work the machines and advanced alchemy knowledge

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any locations or characters?
